# Which information my DNS provider can see?

Tags: security, dns, vpn

I'm studying software engineering, but sometimes I found myself looking for cybersecurity topics.
Yesterday, I found an article on medium entitled "Don't use VPN at home" (https://onezero.medium.com/dont-use-a-vpn-at-home-dd67e753aef5).
I read the article and decided to see the comments section.
While reading the comments I found a comment saying that my ISP can't read my URL, only my domain, but other person argued that if I use the DNS of my ISP, it could read my URL.
**So, I use google open dns, then it means that google can read all my url, right?**
Sorry if I'm shit talking. I'm a complete noob about security.

**TL;DR**: My DNS provider can read all my url and data contained in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DNS server will always know which websites you visit.
It does not matter if you use one from google or the one from your ISP.

This is because everytime you visit a webpage that your computer does not know the IP of, it will send a DNS lookup to find the IP which
maps to the webpages domain (=URL) you visit.

If the DNS owner chooses to keep a log of all traffic,
he will know which pages you visited.
By using a VPN, your ISP will not automatically know which pages you visit, but if you use your ISPs DNS, the ISP will be able to log
which pages you visit.

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere... you ask the right questions, so you're not a noob, keep it up!

Comment: Thank you very much man, that's exactly what i was wondering.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you can operate your VPN in Tunnel Mode, sending **all** communications including DNS through the VPN stack. In this mode,  all DNS queries would use the VPN's DNS. This is the most secure way since all DNS traffic stays in the VPN provider network.

If you want to verify your VPN doesn't leak DNS, you should look into its configuration. there is usually an option which might not be checked by default. You can test it here for example https://www.dnsleaktest.com/

Check with your VPN provider and software. Not all vpns offer these features.